# EF relationship not working for entities in cosmos db

Tags: entity-framework, join, azure-cosmosdb

Hello I'm using EF 7 with cosmos db. I have **one** containers in cosmosdb with entities similar to below 2 classes.

> ```
> public class Ride: AuditEntity
> {
>     [Key]
>     public Guid RideId { get; set; }
>
>     public Guid VehicleId { get; set; }
>
>     public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
>
> }
>
>
> public class Vehicle : AuditEntity
> {
>     public Guid VehicleId { get; set; }
>
>     public string Model { get; set; }
> }
> ```

I have defined the relationship and keys as below: -

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().ToContainer("Rides").HasPartitionKey(o => o.PartitionKey).HasKey(o => o.VehicleId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Ride>().ToContainer("Rides").HasPartitionKey(o => o.PartitionKey);

modelBuilder.Entity<Ride>().HasOne(o => o.Vehicle).WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.VehicleId).HasPrincipalKey(v => v.VehicleId);
```

Now when I try to retrieve a ride by ID along with the vehicle using below LINQ query:-

```
ride = db.Rides.Where(_ => _.PartitionKey == key)
                    .Where(_ => _.IsDeleted == false && _.RideId == id)
                    .Include(m => m.Vehicle) 
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get below error

> ```
> The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Ride>()
>     .Where(r => r.PartitionKey == __loginUser_0)
>     .Where(r => r.IsDeleted == False && r.RideId == __id_1)
>     .Join(
>         inner: DbSet<Vehicle>(), 
>         outerKeySelector: r => EF.Property<Guid?>(r, "VehicleId"), 
>         innerKeySelector: v => EF.Property<Guid?>(v, "VehicleId"), 
>         resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Ride, Vehicle>(
>             Outer = o, 
>             Inner = i
>         ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> ```
>
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information.

ONly solution I can find is to use client-side evaluation by explicitly converting the query to a list using the ToList() or AsEnumerable() method and then do explicit join like this

```
dbContext.Rides
    .Where(r => r.PartitionKey == __loginUser_0 && r.IsDeleted == false && r.RideId == __id_1)
    .ToList()
    .Join(
        inner: dbContext.Vehicles,
        outerKeySelector: r => r.VehicleId,
        innerKeySelector: v => v.VehicleId,
        resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Ride, Vehicle>(
            Outer = o,
            Inner = i
        ))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But I don't want to resort to client-side evaluation as this is a fairly simple and common usecase.Can anyone please help me with this? **Any help is appreciated**. Thanks

Comment: read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512550/how-to-query-from-two-containers-in-cosmos-db-sql-api

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I moved both the entities to same container, still getting same above error.